# Python : How to drop and save null value records from df except few columns?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Last_Name': ['Smith', Null, Null,'Joy'], 
           'First_Name': ['John', Null, 'Bill', 'Tony'],
           'Age': [35, 45, Null, 60], 'Salary':[200,300,Null,500})
```

Like above df, I have 40 columns in my real df. I want to drop all records having Null or empty values except 3 columns(though they have empty values). I mean below code should not apply to those 3 columns even though the values are null and save the records as am doing in df_drop.

```
df_drop = df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore your columns with `drop`:

```
# change this if you want
your_cols = ['Last_Name', 'First_Name', 'Age']

# new dataframe, save this with, e.g., `.to_csv()`
df[df.drop(your_cols, axis=1).notnull().all(1)]
```

Output:

```
  Last_Name First_Name   Age  Salary
0     Smith       John  35.0   200.0
1      None       None  45.0   300.0
3       Joy       Tony  60.0   500.0
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want to save dropped records to csv separately. In this case am not saving dropped records.

Comment: Did you try to_csv?

Comment: CSV contains after dropped records. i want to save only dropped records.

Comment: Then add the negation into the bracket `df[~df.drop(...)]`?

Answer (score -1):

The generic method would be:

```
df.dropna(how='any', axis=1)
```

If you need to exclude some columns, save them to a separate DF, then concat back.
Edit: specifically:

```
cols_to_save = ['A', 'B', 'C']
df = df[cols_to_save].join(df.drop(columns=cols_to_save).dropna(how='any', axis=1))
```

Comment: Please do comment why this isn't working for you (I understand this by the neg vote?). Did I understand the task correctly? This is not for me of course, but for the sake of the community.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Give me some time. Surely I will try and get back. :)

Comment: I got type error : drop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'

Comment: @Rahul that's incomprehensible. `columns` is a legitimate keyword for drop both in 0.2x and 1.0 pandas. In fact, I tried this code snippet, and it worked. Edit: I checked, and you need at least 0.21 for it. If you have an older version, use `labels, axis=1` instead